# Get the position of an object moving using storyboard Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, storyboard, uwp, uwp-xaml, blend-2015

I have two Circle objects both drawn over a canvas.
I'm moving one with a storyboard  created in Blend for visual 2015
now i want to track the moving circle1's position to see when it reaches circle2
tried this:

```
  double x =  Canvas.GetLeft(circle1);
```

but this gets the value before the circle was moved and doesn't track its movement.

Anyone have any idea how to pull this off?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use Blend for Visual Studio 2015, it generates some code like following:

```
<Page ...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" >
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="210" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="114" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Canvas Width="600" Height="600">
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform/>
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In this code, we can find that this movement is achieved by changing `RenderTransform`, especially `TranslateX` and `TranslateY` in storyboard. So the position of the circle is not changed. And while using `Canvas.GetLeft` method, it always returns the value that the circle is set.

To get the "position", we can calculate with the `TranslateX` and `TranslateY` like:

```
var transform = (circle1.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform);
var x = Canvas.GetLeft(circle1) + transform.TranslateX;
var y = Canvas.GetTop(circle1) + transform.TranslateY;
```

Comment: Thanks so much  your explanation was pretty clear and much help